# Add background border color for required field in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am using the required attribute on the `ui:inputText` in a component. Is there a way to implement when required fields that are not filled out get the red border around them after submitting? same behavior how you see in the salesforce classic visualforce page?

here is my component at run time looks like:

[image]

Component:

```
<!-- Input Form using components -->
    <div class="container">
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">

                    <ui:inputText aura:id="expname" label="Expense Name"
                                  class="slds-input"
                                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                  value="{!v.newExpense.Name}"
                                  required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="amount" label="Amount"
                                    class="slds-input"
                                    labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                    value="{!v.newExpense.Amount__c}"
                                    required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="client" label="Client"
                                  class="slds-input"
                                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                  value="{!v.newExpense.Client__c}"
                                    required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
           <ui:button label="Submit" 
                           class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                           labelClass="label"
                           press="{!c.createExpense}"/>

        </form>
    </div><!-- ./container-->
```

Controller:

```
   createExpense : function(component, event, helper) {

        var nameField = component.find("expname");//.get("v.value");
        var nameValue = nameField.get("v.value");

        if($A.util.isEmpty(nameValue) || $A.util.isUndefined(nameValue)){
            nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Enter an expense Name."}]);
        }         
        else {
            //call helper method.
        }
    },
```

Comment: You should get the red border when you have required=true. Do you have an attribute called newexpense in your component?

Comment: yes i do `<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="Expense__c"
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Expense__c',
                             'Name': '',
                             'Amount__c': 0,
                             'Client__c': '', 
                             'Date__c': '',
                             'Reimbursed__c': false
                             }"/>`

Comment: Aren't you seeing the red border when the page loads on the required fields? can you inspect and see if there are any warnings or errors in the console. I tried your code without attribute and it was warning the scope of newexpense is not defined.

Comment: i'm getting the message what i have defined here `nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Enter an expense Name."}]);` but no red border.

Comment: here is the source code that i'm practicing you can get from here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app.htm

Comment: Does your code have a namespace in front of the fieldnames? Leave name as is but for Amount__c try using namespace__Amount__c and lemme know if the red border shows up

Comment: I do not have namespace

Comment: Are you extending force:slds or loading LDS styles from static resource? Arent you getting the required red box not even on the name field in the form ? Also what release is your org in, winter 17 or summer 16? what browser are you working on?

Comment: I'm using winter 17 and I'm not extending anything I have download slds few days ago, using chrome, not getting required red box for name as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a *error* class in your component and add the same when showing the error message.

So when you do `nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"some message"}]);`, error message is shown and **action** specified in `onError` will be invoked and which would add the *error* class to the input box.

And if you do `nameField.set("v.errors",null);`, the *error* message is removed and **action** specified in `onClearErrors` will be invoked and which removes error class from the input box.

Below is how it is done:

**TestApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="test" type="String" default="hellowrodl" />
    <div class="slds">
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="testCmp" label="Name"
                                  class="slds-input"
                                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                                  value="{!v.test}"
                                  required="true" 
                                  onError="{!c.handleError}" 
                                  onClearErrors="{!c.handleClearError}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ui:button label="Submit" 
                       class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                       labelClass="label"
                       press="{!c.validate}"/>

        </form>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**TestAppController.js**

```
({
    validate : function(component, event, helper) {

        var nameField = component.find("testCmp");//.get("v.value");
        var nameValue = nameField.get("v.value");

        if($A.util.isEmpty(nameValue) || $A.util.isUndefined(nameValue)){
            nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Enter a Name"}]);
        }         
        else {
            nameField.set("v.errors",null);
        }
    }, 

    handleError:function(cmp,event,helper){
        var comp = event.getSource();
        $A.util.addClass(comp, "error");   
    },

    handleClearError:function(cmp,event,helper){
        var comp = event.getSource();
        $A.util.removeClass(comp, "error");   
    },
})
```

**TestApp.css**

```
.THIS input.error, .THIS select.error {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(194, 57, 52);
    box-shadow: rgb(194, 57, 52) 0 0 0 1px inset;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.THIS span.required{
    color:#c23934;
}
```

Comment: 1+ I see now the red border... one question though, Is that a typo?, why would you have `<ui:inputText...` in the `app` as appose to `component`?

Comment: To run the component you need an app and include the component in the app.For the sake of example I put logics in the app directly.